# Using a docker command as an variable in a Jenkins sh script?

Tags: docker, jenkins, sh

I am working on a CI/DC Pipeline where I have a DEV, TEST and Prod Server. With a Jenkins Pipeline i deploy my newest Image onto my DEV-Server. Now i want to take the image of my DEV-Server by reading out the sha256 id and put it on my TEST-Server.

I have a Jenkins Pipeline for that:

```
    pipeline {
        
        agent any
        tools {
            dockerTool 'docker-19.03.9'
        }
        
        environment {
            
        }
        
        stages {
            stage('DeployToTEST-Angular') {
                steps {
                    script {
                        echo 'Deploying image...'
                        sh 'docker stop mycontainertest'
                        sh 'docker rm mycontainertest'
                        sh 'docker run -d --name mycontainertest [cant show the envirmoments i give with] --restart always angular:latest'
                    }
                }
                
            }
    }
```

As you see i currently use the :latest tag, but i want something like this:

```
pipeline {
    
    agent any
    tools {
        dockerTool 'docker-19.03.9'
    }
    
    environment {
        
    }
    
    stages {
        stage('DeployToTEST-Angular') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'Deploying image...'
                    sh 'docker stop mycontainertest'
                    sh 'docker rm mycontainertest'
                    sh 'docker run -d --name mycontainertest [cant show the envirmoments i give with] --restart always \$imageofDev'
                }
            }
            
        }
}
```

**$imageofDev = docker inspect mycontainerdev | grep -o 'sha256:[^"]*'** // this command works and give my back the raw sha256 number

So that it uses the actuall sha256 number of my dev image

I dont know how i can define this variable and later use the value of it in this Jenkins Pipeline. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you build the image, choose an image name and tag that you can remember later.  Jenkins provides several [environment variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#using-environment-variables) that you can use to construct this, such as `BUILD_NUMBER`; in a [multibranch pipeline](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/multibranch/#additional-environment-variables) you also have access to `BRANCH_NAME` and `CHANGE_ID`; or you can directly run `git` in your pipeline code.

```
def shortCommitID = sh script: 'git rev-parse --short HEAD', returnStdout: true
def dockerImage = "project:${shortCommitID.trim()}"
def registry = 'registry.example.com'
def fullDockerImage "${registry}/${dockerImage}"
```

Now that you know the Docker image name you're going to use everywhere you can just use it; you never need to go off and look up the image ID.  Using the [scripted pipeline Docker integration](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#advanced-usage-with-scripted-pipeline), for example:

```
docker.withRegistry("https://${registry}") {
  def image = docker.build(dockerImage)
  image.push
}
```

Since you know the `registry/image:tag` name, you can just use it in other Jenkins directives too

```
def containerName = 'container'

// stop an old container, if any
sh "docker stop ${containerName} || true"
sh "docker rm ${containerName} || true"

// start a new container that outlives this pipeline
sh "docker run -d --name ${containerName} ${fullDockerImage}"
```

Comment: Thank you, i found a answer by myself but your idea help me :)